# Create Desktop shortcut to background app termination

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts

Is it possible, and if so how, to create a shortcut (e.g. on the desktop) for terminating a background app? This is instead of `Start Menu->Type Name of app->App settings->Terminate`.

To be specific, I want to create such a shortcut for the mail app. The use case, if anyone is interested, is forcing a restart after changing proxy settings as one of the mail servers cannot connect once  the change is made until proper termination. This is not the same as closing the application (pressing the X in this case).

I'll note that the associated service isn't really running (at least visibly) while the app is closed (but still operates in the background), and so I couldn't get a simple `taskkill` batch file to work.

Comment: Why don't you make a file that can do it like a batch file? AFAIK you should be able to make a shortcut to certain programs that can terminate stuff, for example a shortcut to cmd.exe like `%comspec% /c "taskkill /t /f /im name.exe"`

Comment: @NekoMusume The problem is, this is a background app - if I open it I'll see the relevant services (`HxOutlook.exe`, `HxTsr.exe`) appear, and closing them does close it, but that's not "true" termination. I'll edit my question.